# Firestore security rules based on an other documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to give user the ability to read a document only if a field in this document is equal to a field in a list of other documents.

My database is like this:

Orders collection

```
 Order 1
    id: order1
 Order 2
    id: order2
```

OrderLines collection

```
 ljsdfozdkfjz
    order: order1
 ozjehfeofheof
    order: order1
 ojezihfoekfjf
    order: order32
 pjeopajfoekfss
    order: order69
```

Here I would like user to be able to read all order lines in OrderLines collection if the document contains the order id of orders the user has access.

I tried this security rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /OrderLines/{OrderLinesId=**} {
        allow read: if resource.data.order == get(/databases/$(database)/Orders/{OrderId}).data.id;
    }
  }
}
```

but it's not working

Comment: Can you clarify where `{OrderId}` comes from?

Answer (score 2):

There are some limitations of security rules that you should be aware of.  First, you can't perform a query in rules.  You can only indicate that you want to read a single document.  You must be able to reference that document by its unique path.  Reading an entire collection is not possible.  Second, you are limited to 10 document reads per rule.

Given your current setup, it's not possible to write a rule that meets your needs.  You might want to consider a different (additional) database structure instead, maybe one that requires a single document with a field that's an array of values to check against.